# Ponteiros de classes inexistentes em C++, como funciona?

Tags: c++, classes

As vezes me deparo em situações como esta:

```
#ifndef CRIARVENDA_H
#define CRIARVENDA_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "cliente.h"

namespace Ui {
class CriarVenda;
}

class CriarVenda : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CriarVenda(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CriarVenda();

private:
    Ui::CriarVenda *ui;
    Cliente *cliente;
};

#endif // CRIARVENDA_H
```

neste caso

```
namespace Ui {
class CriarVenda;
}
```

É criado uma espécie de um protótipo de um classe que ainda vai ser criada o que não faz muito sentido.

Neste caso ainda não faz mas sentido ainda, onde ele cria um "Protótipo de classe"

```
#ifndef CPU_HPP
#define CPU_HPP

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

class GameBoy;
```

Cria um ponteiro para a mesma

```
GameBoy* gameboy;

    public:
        CPU( GameBoy& core );

#include "GameBoy.hpp"
#include "CPU.hpp"
#include "RAM.hpp"

CPU::CPU( GameBoy& core ) :
    gameboy( &core ) {
    initOpcodeArray();
}

std::uint8_t CPU::readMem( std::uint16_t address ) {
    gameboy->ram.readMem( address );
}

void CPU::writeMem( std::uint16_t address, std::uint8_t value ) {
    gameboy->ram.writeMem( address, value );
}
```

Depois chama até os membros da classe.

Qual é o nome disso? Estou olhando uns livros de C++ que tenho e não vejo nada do tipo, e para que serve?

Comment: Claro que faz sentido, é pra que a classe seja acessivel quando `Ui` criar o objeto a partir de Form (que é um Xml que irá gerar o .cpp só no pre-build), esse cpp para o form é gerado dinamicamente. E pré criar classes é util assim, você precisa criar um var que o tipo é da classe `Gameboy` isso no HPP, mas a classe é só incluida no CPP, então você já pré-declara e coloca lá a sua var `class FooBar {private: Gameboy *var1; }`.

Comment: Qual o nome desta técnica e qual as vantagens dela?

Comment: Uma vantagem é ter a pre-classe acessivel para poder declarar variaveis do tipo desta classe especifica antes de incluir ela, mas talvez deva existir "mais vantagens", todavia se vc for fazer um `#include` direto em outro .hpp não teria muito sentido pré-declarar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na forma usada não tem sentido. Isto chama-se [*forward declaration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration), isto é necessário em compiladores que faz a análise do código em apenas um passo (curiosamente isto não ocorre em C++, mas por compatibilidade com C, porque C++ tem muito contexto para ser analisado e outros motivos mais específicos, não é feito).

É útil quando você precisa que em casos de uso cíclico, ou seja, você vai usar um tipo em outro tipo que será usado no primeiro tipo. Como declarar algo que não existe? Então faz-se uma declaração simples sem dizer o que terá dentro para o tipo existir e poder ser usado em outro tipo, aí este tipo existindo você pode pode usá-lo para declarar completamente o tipo anterior que depende desta declaração.

O ponteiro em si nada tem a ver com isso.